# Is it possible to use temporary column in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

1. I want to display only the data where the `RequestStatus_hod` is `IN PROCESS`
2. But the query seems to display all of the data by ignoring the where clause
3. As you can see, I've tried to repeat `WHERE RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'` but it just displays as `NULL`
4. I've tried to use the temporary column `RequestStatus_hods` and received `an invalid column error`

SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   A.RequestNumber, A.EmployeeId,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(B.RequestDetailsId AS VARCHAR(255))
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS RequestDetailIds,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(B.StockId AS VARCHAR(255))
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId 
          JOIN [dbo].[STOCK] F ON F.StockId = B.StockId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS StockIds,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(B.RequestQuantity AS VARCHAR(255))
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS RequestQuantity,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + G.ItemName
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId 
          JOIN [dbo].[STOCK] F ON F.StockId = B.StockId 
          JOIN [dbo].[ITEM_MASTER] G ON F.ItemId = G.ItemId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS ItemNames,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(F.StockQuantity AS VARCHAR(255))
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId 
          JOIN [dbo].[STOCK] F ON F.StockId = B.StockId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS AvailableQuantity,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + B.RequestStatus_hod
           FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
           JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId
           WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
           FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS RequestStatus_hods -- Temporary Column --
FROM 
    [dbo].[REQUISITION] A
JOIN
    [dbo].[USER] D ON D.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId
JOIN
    [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] E ON E.EmployeeId = D.EmployeeId
WHERE 
    RequestStatus_hods = 'IN PROCESS' -- Col RequestStatus_hod FROM table REQUISITION_DETAILS --
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: is it **RequestStatus_hods** or **RequestStatus_hod**, as your temporary column says RequestStatus_hods but your where condition says RequestStatus_hod

Comment: @CodingDefined Actually i wanna filter the temporary column `RequestStatus_hods` . `RequestStatus_hod` is the original column from table `REQUISITION_DETAILS`

Comment: add condition `B.RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'` in where condition of the last select.

Comment: @CodingDefined Yes i've tried that already and it displays as `NULL` on the temporary column and still the rest of the column from the same rows displays the data. And i've tried to add where clause like i've commented on my syntax but the results are the same. Return as `NULL`

Comment: Try This `FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId AND B.RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'`

Comment: @CodingDefined I've tried that too, still the same :( I've tried `E.RequestStatus_hod = B.RequestStatus_hod` and then `B.RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'` and still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66175/discussion-between-codingdefined-and-athirah-hazira).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to repeat the definition for your temporary column inside the `WHERE` clause. SQL Server doesn't support using an alias inside a `WHERE` directly, but it is still smart enough (in most cases) to figure out that the expression does not need to be evaluated twice. So, instead of writing `RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'` inside your `WHERE`, just copy and paste the actual definition of the column in place of where it says `RequestStatus_hods`.

*However*, an even better choice might be to extract your column into an `APPLY` clause. This way, you know for sure that it won't be run twice.

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   A.RequestNumber, A.EmployeeId,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(B.RequestDetailsId AS VARCHAR(255))
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS RequestDetailIds,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(B.StockId AS VARCHAR(255))
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId 
          JOIN [dbo].[STOCK] F ON F.StockId = B.StockId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS StockIds,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(B.RequestQuantity AS VARCHAR(255))
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS RequestQuantity,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + G.ItemName
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId 
          JOIN [dbo].[STOCK] F ON F.StockId = B.StockId 
          JOIN [dbo].[ITEM_MASTER] G ON F.ItemId = G.ItemId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS ItemNames,
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(F.StockQuantity AS VARCHAR(255))
          FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
          JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId 
          JOIN [dbo].[STOCK] F ON F.StockId = B.StockId
          WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId -- AND RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') AS AvailableQuantity,
    xx.RequestStatus_hods -- Temporary Column --
FROM 
    [dbo].[REQUISITION] A
JOIN
    [dbo].[USER] D ON D.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId
JOIN
    [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] E ON E.EmployeeId = D.EmployeeId
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + B.RequestStatus_hod
           FROM [dbo].[REQUISITION] C 
           JOIN [dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] B ON C.RequestDetailsId = B.RequestDetailsId
           WHERE C.RequestNumber = A.RequestNumber AND C.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId 
           FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') as RequestStatus_hods) xx
WHERE 
    xx.RequestStatus_hods = 'IN PROCESS' -- Col RequestStatus_hod FROM table REQUISITION_DETAILS --
```

Comment: Theres an error on both `xx.RequestStatus_hods` : `The multi-part identifier could not be bound` **AND** on `STUFF` after the `CROSS APPLY` : `Invalid object name STUFF`

Comment: @AthirahHazira Sorry, missed a small piece! Just edited it. Try again please

Answer (score 0):

try

WHERE E.RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `WHERE` clause completely and try this instead

```
JOIN
[dbo].[REQUISITION_DETAILS] E
ON E.EmployeeId = D.EmployeeId
AND E.RequestStatus_hod = 'IN PROCESS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all, let's call things with their names, RequestStatus_hods is not a "temporary column", it's a calculation placed in a column of the resultset of the query with an alias "RequestStatus_hods".

I don't really understand those solutions involving CROSS JOINS, so I can't assess them, but I guess that performance is not the best in those cases.

I have two different approaches for this kind of problems
1.- Instead of "RequestStatus_hods" in the where clause, use exactly the same expression that your are using to build the value in the column. It will work, but the performance will be affected if the resultset contains lots of records.
2.- I surround the query as follows

```
SELECT * FROM ( <YOUR-QUERY> ) AS 
RESULTSET WHERE RESULTSET.[RequestStatus_hods] = 'IN PROCESS'
```

so your query becomes an internal-made up temporary table (depends on who the engine resolves the query) but the effect is that you have the table you want with the fields you want. The performance with this approach usually is not very bad.

Hope this helps.